# How to set CORS on specific asset files with Sails js

Tags: cors, sails.js, assets

I have assets (angular template files) on a server powered by Sails.js with a domain.
I have another domain with an angular application which needs templates from my first server. In order to do it, I need to set CORS on asset files from my first server with sailsJs.

I found how to set sails js CORS on a specific route but not on specific assets..
Have you informations about it ? thanks :)

Comment: if possible add some code snippet which you've tried.

Comment: @agpt I didn't try any code snippet because i didn't find any doc about it, just doc about specific routes : [link](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/bc148104378f1ad590a69220c25f60fe41a59790/config.cors.md) but it's not my case..

Answer (score 0):

The docs tell you all you need--assets can be routes, too:

```
// config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {

  "/templates/someTemplate.html": {cors: true}

}
```

By not specifying a handler for the route (like a controller/action combo or a view), you tell Sails to respond in the default manner (by sending the asset file), but with the additional CORS headers added.

FYI more updated docs are available on [SailsJS.org](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.cors.html).